# Use string as type of DbSet like DbSet<string> in EF-CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I want to have a list of string and save and load them to/from database using EF-CodeFirst. this is my DbContext class:

```
public class KeysDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<string> Keys { get; set; }
}
```

but when I try to run the code I get this exception:`System.InvalidOperationException` : `The type 'System.String' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.`

How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a `DbSet<string>`. String is treated as a primitive type by EF and the type for the DbSet has to be an entity. Entity has properties (which usually are mapped to columns in database) and also have to have keys. If, in your database you have a table that has just one string column you would have to create an entity with a string property to model this. In addition the string property will have to be a key property.

Comment: thanks. and one more question: how can I make EF-CodeFirst to generate the key by itself?

Comment: You mean by the database right? EF does not generate key - either you have to set the key value or have the database generate it for you. For int keys EF by default creates Identity columns. You can change it using DatabaseGeneratedAttribute.