# How to make a repository for class with <T> in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I have a simple class:

```
public class TestClass<T> {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Is is possible to use EF Code First and Repository pattern to save this kind of elements to SQL database?

---

**Edit**:
It seems like the DbSet's cannot be created using the  -notation. E.g.

```
public class UnitOFWorkTestContext : DbContext {
    ...
    public DbSet<TestClass<int>> TestClass_Int { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Gives error:

*The type 'UnitOFWorkTest.Models.TestClass`1[System.Int32]' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.*

Comment: Tried scaffolding in Visual Studio by right -clicking "Controllers" and selecting "Add -> Controller" and also with Package Manager Console with command "Scaffold Controller TestClass<T>" (I have the "MVC Scaffolding" -package installed)

Comment: Then what output did u get?

Comment: From Package Manager Console:

    Scaffold : Cannot find a model type corresponding to a controller called 'TestClass<T>'. Try supplying a -ModelType parameter value.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Scaffold Controller TestClass<T>
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Scaffolder], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.InvokeScaffolderCmdlet

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm just testing the proposed solutions...

Comment: you can pass only class object

Answer (score 5):

Below is the copy of my own working code. I do not pretending that my code is perfect, but it is handy and has loose coupleness. Also, it will be quite big amount of code, but do not be afraid =)...

**IEntity:**

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**AbstractRepository and interface:**

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> List();
    IEnumerable<T> List(Func<T, bool> pred);

    T Get(int id);
    T Get(Func<T, bool> pred);

    void Add(T entity);

    T Update(T entity);

    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(Func<T, bool> pred);
}

public abstract class AbstractRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    protected TContext context;

    public AbstractRepository(UnitOfWork<TContext> unit)
    {
        context = unit.Context;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> List()
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> List(Func<TEntity, bool> pred)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(pred);
    }

    public virtual TEntity Get(int id)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public virtual TEntity Get(Func<TEntity, bool> pred)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(pred);
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity.Id <= 0)
            context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
    }

    public virtual TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity.Id > 0)
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            return entity;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(Func<TEntity, bool> pred)
    {
        foreach (var entity in List(pred))
        {
            Delete(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

**Concrete repository:**

```
public class GroupRepository : AbstractRepository<Group, SurveyContext>
{
    public GroupRepository(UnitOfWork<SurveyContext> unit)
        : base(unit)
    {
    }
}
```

**DbContext successor:**

```
public class SurveyContext: DbContext
{
    public SurveyContext() : base("name=ApplicationConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Optional
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Confuration1());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Confuration2());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Confuration3());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GroupConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

**Unit of work:**

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IDisposable
    where TContext: DbContext, new()
{
    public TContext Context { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWork(TContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public UnitOfWork() : this(new TContext())
    {
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
using (var unit = new UnitOfWork<SurveyContext>())
{
    //ViewDataSynchronize.SynchronizeSectionsForGroup(context, model.SectionIds, model.Group);

    var repo = new GroupRepository(unit);
    repo.Add(model.Group);
    unit.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank You for an excellent answer! I tried your example and got the solution working. It seems like the DbSet's cannot be created using the <T> -notation. E.g. 
`public class UnitOFWorkTestContext : DbContext {
...
public DbSet<TClass<int>> TClass_Int { get; set; }
...`
Gives error: 
_The type 'UnitOFWorkTest.Models.TClass`1[System.Int32]' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject._

Comment: It seems that following questions explains your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000748/use-string-as-type-of-dbset-like-dbsetstring-in-ef-codefirst

Comment: Are you trying to use plain .NET type instead of class? It will not works.

Comment: @alex-g-p I got your solution working with simple classes, but not classes with signature like `public class Test<T> {}` It seems like these don't classify as class?

Comment: Yep, if you will use generic classes it will be a bit harder because you should specify templates explicitly anywhere you using it.