# C# database abstraction class with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext

I want to create a common database abstraction in order to expose the same interface without worrying about the type of the `DbContext` that the database manage.

Here there is an example in order to explain well the concept:

```
public interface IDatabase<T> where T : DbContext {
    void Add<T>(T entity);
    void Remove<T>(T entity);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

The implementation can be:

```
public MyDatabase<T> : IDatabase<T> where T : MyContext {
    public T Context { get; private set; }

    //singleton contructor ...

    public void Add<TC>(TC entity) {
        Context.Set<TC>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Remove<TC>(TC entity) {
        Context.Set<TC>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void SaveChanges {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The goals of this design are different: expose the same interface in order to decouple logic from database, change quickly the database (context), create one time the context and reuse during all the application lifetime (lock mechanism are required).

The problem is that the interface hides all the types of the sets in the context.

```
Context.Set<TC>().Add(entity);    //this line don't compile
```

I'm not sure that this design is the best practise. How can I implement a design that offers these features?

Comment: It is good solution. You can take a look to my answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712177/how-to-make-a-repository-for-class-with-t-in-ef/16712776#16712776

Comment: It's called the Repository pattern, often the repository pattern is used with the unit of work pattern. You can look at this example: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

Why you does not use the standard pattern for example Repository pattern you can also combine it with UnitOfWork.
You make it complicated for your self, just check this.

```
 public interface IMyClassRepository : IDisposable
  {
    IQueryable<MyClass> All { get; }
    IQueryable<MyClass> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<MyClass, object>>[] includeProperties);
    MyClass Find(int id);
    void InsertOrUpdate(MyClass myClass);
    void Delete(int id);
    void Save();
  }

  public class MyClassRepository : IMyClassRepository
  {
    DBContext context = new DBContext();
    public IQueryable<MyClass> All
    {
      get { return context.Employees; }
    }
    public IQueryable<MyClass> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<MyClass, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
      IQueryable<MyClass> query = context.MyClasses;
      foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
      {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
      }
      return query;
    }
    public MyClass Find(int id)
    {
      return context.MyClasses.Find(id);
    }
    public void InsertOrUpdate(MyClass myClass)
    {
      if (myClass.Id == default(int))
      {
        // New entity
        context.MyClasses.Add(myClass);
      }
      else
      {
        // Existing entity
        context.Entry(myClass).State = EntityState.Modified;
      }
    }
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
      var employee = context.Employees.Find(id);
      context.Employees.Remove(employee);
    }
    public void Save()
    {
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
      context.Dispose();
    }
  }

  public class MyClass
  {
  }
```