# Convert EF6 to EF core with the ObjectResult

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have some code I am trying to convert.  I don't have these ObjectResult and ObjectContext anymore

This is what I did have:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<string> GetTransData(string iN_MEM_ID)
{
    var iN_MEM_IDParameter = iN_MEM_ID != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("IN_MEM_ID", iN_MEM_ID) :
        new ObjectParameter("IN_MEM_ID", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("GetTransData", iN_MEM_IDParameter);
}
```

Since I need a List to be returned from a caller  ( it is sent back as json data )

This is what I am trying to build

```
public virtual List<string> GetTransData(string iN_MEM_ID)
    {
        var iN_MEM_IDParameter = iN_MEM_ID != null ?
               new SqlParameter("IN_MEM_ID", iN_MEM_ID) :
               new SqlParameter("IN_MEM_ID", typeof(string));

       Clinical_CaseTrakker_Context clinical = new Clinical_CaseTrakker_Context();


        List<string> offLine = clinical.string.FromSql("EXECUTE CT.GetTransData {0}", iN_MEM_IDParameter);

        return offLine;
    }
```

Notice that I am stuck with `clinical.string`   i can't do that , but I am not sure how to take dbcontext instance and run FromSql to execute sql and return to List

Comment: clinical...... what?.FromSql(   i'm lost on how to do that when usually i use some dbset property ... but this code conversion needs to return list<string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF Core, it is not possible to use the `FromSql` method to return a subset of properties (a projection) directly from the database.
You are required to define a some model and a `DbSet` for that class

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

then declare in your context

```
public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

and use it like:

```
using (var context = new Clinical_CaseTrakker_Context())
{
   var offLine = context.Foos
      .FromSql($"EXECUTE CT.GetTransData {iN_MEM_IDParameter}")
      .Select(x => x.Bar)
      .ToList();

   return offLine;
}
```

Comment: Let me try that.   Do I need virtual at all ?

Comment: I just need to add tolist at the end.  changed from  .Select(x => x.Bar);  to  .Select(x => x.Bar).ToList();     thx again

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: This makes me cringe. EF6 ExecuteFunction is parameterized. Ef core wants to replace the safety of parameters with string interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

Your Context needs a `virtual DbSet<string> ResultStrings { get; set; }` that you can call upon and put the result in. (This does not work, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000748/use-string-as-type-of-dbset-like-dbsetstring-in-ef-codefirst) or Roman Marusyk comment below)

EDIT: Your Context needs a `virtual DbSet<ResultEntity> ResultEntities { get; set; }` that you can call upon and put the result in.

Then you can do `return clinical.ResultEntities.FromSql("EXECUTE CT.GetTransData {0}", iN_MEM_IDParameter").toList()` to fill the set.

Considering the `ResultEntity` has an `Id` and a `value` property, you can do `ResultEntities.Select(e => e.value).toList()` to extract a list of strings from the set.

Comment: You cannot have a DbSet<string>. String is treated as a primitive type by EF and the type for the DbSet has to be an entity.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering about that , thus sounds like I need to use Database.ExecuteSqlCommand

Comment: @JeremyMiller No, because this method returns an integer specifying the number of rows affected by the SQL statement passed to it.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk  you deleted your answer?   I had a question about the offline...

Comment: @pjominet  where does ResultEntity come from?  i see you edited, do you feel your answer will work ?

Comment: you have to create this entity yourself, something that has the same properties as the result columns from your sql query